# Update-SPSolution & Items in a Document Library

Tags: solution-package, versioning, feature-upgrade

I have the following situation:

solution1.wsp that has a document library with files inside (I use a module element for adding new files to the feature)

and solution2.wsp that has a document library with different files inside (with new files in a module)

I have tried to use the `Update-SPSolution` cmdlet, but with no success. The document library items were not changed.

I have investigated `Update-SPSolution`'s behavior and it is probably impossible to add new items (in a module element).

Is it possible to add new items to a feature via a module and then do `Update-SPSolution` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find answer to my question. Yes, you can. You can use  element. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537916(v=office.14).aspx
And use same file elements.xml with new content.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed description of the `Update-SPSolution` at [MSDN - Update-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 says:

> The `Update-SPSolution` cmdlet upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution in the farm. Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files and features as the deployed solution. **If files and features are different, the solution must be retracted and redeployed by using the `Uninstall-SPSolution` and `Install-SPSolution` cmdlets, respectively.**

So unfortunately, no, you can't add new files to a document library via a module by using `Update-SPSolution`.

Comment: I have find answer to my question. Yes, you can. You can use <ApplyElementManifests> element.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537916(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: This will add the files from both of your elements.xml files, not just replace the old ones with the new ones.

Comment: But we can use this element(<ApplyElementManifests>) and use file with same name elements.xml but with different content to replace old file elements.xml with new file elements.xml. All new items that we will add actually appears in folder of the new feature and after upgrade command my document library(like in my example) contains new files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new files to document library using **Update-SPSolution** but instead  you can build a feature that creates (or to an already created document library) a document library including some **default documents** already in the library. The feature should be web scoped, include a list instance element and a module element with all the necessary content files. By changing the URL parameter in the module you can ensure that the documents are placed in the new/existing document library.

Here is a [smart example](http://jcapka.blogspot.se/2011/05/deploying-document-library-including.html) on how to do it.

Comment: I have find answer to my question. Yes, you can. You can use <ApplyElementManifests> element.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537916(v=office.14).aspx